# Error deploying Rails 4.2 with Capistrano 3.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I'm in the process of deploying my rails application to production and keep running into an `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Array into String` error.  This is my first real deployment attempt, so I'm at a loss for where to start with debugging the error.

```
EBUG [634578b1] Finished in 0.179 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [e1912f46] Running bundle exec rake assets:precompile as deploy@107.170.60.189
DEBUG [e1912f46] Command: cd /opt/www/testapp/releases/20150325215252 && ( RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile )
DEBUG [e1912f46]    rake aborted!
DEBUG [e1912f46]    TypeError: no implicit conversion of Array into String
DEBUG [e1912f46]    /opt/www/testapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/key_generator.rb:21:in `pbkdf2_hmac_sha1'
DEBUG [e1912f46]    /opt/www/testapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/key_generator.rb:21:in `generate_key'
DEBUG [e1912f46]    /opt/www/testapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/key_generator.rb:38:in `generate_key'
```

Does anyone have any experience with this error or have a good starting point for me to look?

Answer (score 2):

It's failing in the `assets:precompile` step, you can try that yourself in your local machine by running:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile assets:clobber
```

If that gives you the same error then you know the issue isn't anything to do with Capistrano, but rather something to do with your assets.  Maybe you can see where the problem is happening, or otherwise debug by looking though your `app/assets/*` files and seeing if there's something obvious to fix there.

Comment: Looks like the error occurs locally also. Problem in the bundler gem maybe? `/home/patrick/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/definition.rb:62:in 'initialize': cannot load such file -- \d]* (LoadError)
 from /home/patrick/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:152:in 'new'`

Comment: You should edit your question and add that error, so it can be formatted properly.